# PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted

Tags: putty, qt-creator

I am using putty from windows vista to connect to ubuntu server and run my qtcreator using Xming.

I am able to log-in into the server, but I am unable to run qtcreator. the following message appears:

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted
PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted
PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted
PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted
qtcreator: cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0
```

so, I search on the net and I found this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253336/i-am-getting-a-putty-attempted-incorrect-protocol-errors-when-i-ssh-into-my-serv/310594#310594), and I tried to follow the answer. however, when I execute xauth list nothing is shown.

accordingly, xauth list command should return me the key (and I dont know what this key is). this key should be added later to xauth. eventually everthing shouold go fine and I should be able to run qtcreator.

- so, in plain english, why this error happens ?
- and why xauth is not returning anything ?
- and finally what is this key ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem which was very simple:

There wasn't enough disk-space on the server. Thus, when `Xming` attempts to create the `.Xauthority` file it fails (i.e.: since this file is being created every time a particular application is lunched, e.g.: qt-creator, it fails to override the old version of itself which can still be seen when listing the files using `ls`) ..

So, after simply removing all unnecessary big files and creating space for the Xming on the disk, I am able to see qt-creator again on my local machine  ..

Comment: This worked for me!  Thanks.  For others, the .Xauthority file was being created in my home directory but it was empty (b/c I was over my quota for the home dir).  Try `ls -l ~` and check if the .Xauthority file is empty (b/c at least in my case it shouldn't be).

Answer (score 1):

On the server, open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Edit the ForwardX11Trusted line to read yes. If no such line exists, add it in.

```
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Restart the ssh server and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I tried to open the file by writing `xdg-open sshd_config` but it is not opening ?

Comment: again when I use `gedit sshd_config` is also not opening !! .. both commands give me this message: `PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted`  .. so, again, having the same problem !!!

Comment: You need to editi it on the SERVER. My guess would be you need to use nano in the putty termina. `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: thanks @bodhi.zazen .. I was able to open the file and edit it. However, I am still having the same problem and the same message !!! .. if I may ask, does "restarting the ssh server" means I should restart  the putty and the Xming ? because I just did that ..

Comment: either reboot the server or `sudo service ssh start` You do not need to restart putty or xming.